# Slack bot python: How to know if received message was in a group or a direct message

Tags: python, slack

I read messages to a bot in python using:

```
messages = client.rtm_read()
for message in messages:
    print(message)
```

But how do I know if this was a DM to the bot, or a message in a group chat that the bot belongs to? Right now, the above always prints dict of the format:

`{'type': 'message', 'channel': 'XXX', 'user': 'YYY', 'text': 'some-message', 'ts': '1485331695.000024', 'team': 'XXX'}`

That's for both DM or group chat.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
import time
while True:
    messages = client.rtm_read()
    if len(messages):
        ...
    time.sleep(<seconds you prefer>)
```